# SQL Select * from table sum and group by id

Tags: php, sql

I need a small help to group and sum the qty for the item id.

Data from database:

```
products
id  code    name            price
1   1234    Product name    12
2   1235    Product name    12
3   1236    Product name    12

warehouses_products
product_id   warehouse_id   quantity
1           1               12
2           1               0
2           2               3
3           1               1
3           2               1
```

PHP Getting the data.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data2;charset=utf8', 'user2', 'Password');

foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM products as pr INNER JOIN warehouses_products AS s ON (s.product_id = pr.id) group by pr.id') as $row) {
echo $row["code"] . ' ' . $row["quantity"];
}
```

an example: if i have the same code on 2 warehouses this is getting only 1 of them, what i want is to sum the quantity and group by product_id.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
'SELECT *, SUM(s.quantity) AS sum_quantity FROM products as pr INNER JOIN warehouses_products AS s ON (s.product_id = pr.id) group by pr.id'
```

In your `foreach` :

```
echo $row["code"] . ' ' . $row["sum_quantity"];
```

Comment: @Dario : In stack overflow we say thanks by accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, SUM(wp.quantity) as quantity
FROM products p
JOIN warehouses_products wp ON wp.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.code
```

PHP:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=data2;charset=utf8', 'user2', 'Password');

foreach($db->query('SELECT p.id, p.code, SUM(wp.quantity) as quantity FROM products p JOIN warehouses_products wp ON wp.product_id = p.id GROUP BY p.id, p.code') as $row) {
echo $row["code"] . ' ' . $row["quantity"];
}
```

Bare in mind that we are relying on the fact that code and id in the product table are a unique pair.